# Trying to get index of item in a Numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm working on an A* pathing project in Python for school (my teacher suggested that I ask this here) and I'm trying to get the indices of an item in the 2D array (i.e. I want to get which "list" it's in in the array and then find the position in that "list" so I can get kind of an (x,y) coordinate of it (if that makes any sense).

This is what I have; I'm taking the data from the array "data" and trying to put it into the "h" array:

```
for e in data:
    np.append(h, np.asarray(np.where(data == e)))
```

When I print h, it returns an empty array.

What I want to get is something like:

```
h = [[x, y], [x, y]...[x, y]]
```

Comment: Please show an MCVE. You're almost there. Just need to show a toy `data` and initialization of `h`. I'm pretty sure there's a much better way of doing this, but I need more info.

Comment: It's not list and sublist in numpy. It's row and column of the matrix. With practice, you will begin to adjust your way of thinking to numpy's differences. But for now, the better way to make sure we're on the same page is to show rather than tell.

Comment: Ping me when you make the changes